# MR with commit behind is dangerous?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am just not quite sure about this operation: *merge the MR even if there are commits behind*.

Are there any lurking issues if I leave the commits behind when merging the MR while there are no **conflicts** at all?

Do I have to make sure the MR is updated without any commit behind every time?

---

Sorry for the misleading terms:

- `MR` is used in Gitlab as that `Pull Request` in GitHub;
- `commits behind` means the there are some commits in master while feature branch lacks

There are no conflicts at all; and that's the root cause making me wonder, why I have to `rebase` or `merge` the master to keep the feature branch updated since there are no conflicts?

Comment: At the risk of showing my ignorance what is an 'MR' in git?  Googling "MR git" suggests you might be referring to GitLab Merge Requests which parallel GitHubs pull-requests?

Comment: @simon-pearson I also don't know what MR is. A "merge request" does make sense but I am still not sure. I'd also like to add - what is "commits behind"? I'm familiar with Git but I am not familiar with this terminology. I can't map it to a specific concept - does it mean that the merge is still *lacking* commits, as in, it's a merge with an older version of the origin branch? Does it mean that there are more commits *after* the merge was done but aren't on the origin branch yet? Maybe it's something else?

Comment: I believe it means there are commits on the origin branch that are not in the feature branch.  A related link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/36534

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "MR" you're referring to GitLab Merge Requests (their analogue to GitHub's pull requests): the risk of merging a branch with commits that are behind the target branch is that those commits which are on the target branch and not in your branch might be incompatible with the code on your branch.  Each branch could be fine in isolation and the problem will only surface when the code is combined.

e.g. what if one of the commits that's on the target branch removes a method which code added in your branch depends on?  The target branch has been adjusted so it compiles and everything is fine, but the target branch doesn't have the new code added by your branch in it so can't update your code.  When you merge your branch in to the target branch that method will be missing and you'll have broken the build.

**The fix:** As a rule of thumb before completing a merge/pull request always merge the target latest of the target branch into your branch (or rebase onto the target branch), and then run all of your tests locally before completing a MR.

Answer (score 0):

You created a branch B off of branch A and while you were working on B someone worked on A. So now B is behind A. You should merge A into your branch B (so that you are up to date), or perhaps rebase B to play out on top of the current state of A, before asking to merge from your branch B back to A.